Parameterizing DFT eigenvectors in terms of Dirichlet characters
I am writing some SageMath code to compute the eigenvectors of the DFT of a cyclic group over the complex numbers. Morton's '80 paper "On the eigenvectors of Schurs matrix" gives a method for doing this using some number theory, namely Dirichlet characters and divisors of the modulus over the conductor.
The code is almost working, but I don't understand how he's counting the eigenvectors. Supposedly for each quadruple $(\chi,\overline{\chi},d,q/fd)$ the eigenvectors listed on pg. 126 in (15) are independent. He goes on to count $\sum_{\chi}\sum_{d|q/f} 1 =q$.
In my code, I iterate over Dirichlet characters $\chi$ and divisors $d$, but I get 1, 2, or 4 eigenvectors for each pair $(\chi,d)$, so I get extra dependent eigenvectors.
For example, for $q=4$ there is a real $\chi$ with $f=1$ and $d=1, q/fd=4$ and $d=4, q/fd=1$ giving dependent eigenvectors.
What is the actual bijection between the $q$ independent eigenvectors and $\chi$, d data?
